# How to assign title to Web Form using Master Page in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms, title, master-pages

I want to assign an individual title for each page that I add to my solution in VS 2010. I noticed that the Site.Master's title is always displayed on the top of my browser.

Even if I specify a title on a Web Form, I still can't see the title, it shows the one on the Site.Master.

Is there a way that the `Site.Master` can either inherit the title of a WebForm or simply allow the WebForm to show it's title?

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/03/tipjar-title-tags-and-master-pages.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this a little while ago, and was surprised that it wasn't as straight forward as it seems if you're unfamiliar with it, but my solution was to put the title in the page directive like so:

```
<%@ Page Title="myTitle" Language="vb" ...
```

in the pages that were being navigated. I don't have title anywhere in my master page either.